# How can i execute a function where columns and function inputs have the same name?

Tags: postgresql, insert, plpgsql

i am trying to create two functions one that inserts and one that deletes rows from this table:

```
CREATE TABLE person
firstName |lastName |age
Lebron    |James    |35
Steph     |Curry    |33
Kevin     |Durant   |31
Nikola    |Jokic    |26
```

I was asked to create these 2 functions using 3 parameters as an input into the functions ,firstName , lastName,age.

As far as insertion is concerned i had no problem creating my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_function(firstName character varying(45)
                                   ,lastName character varying(45) ,age character varying(45))
                                
                                                                       -
RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO person (firstName , lastName , age)
VALUES (firstName , lastName , age);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Although the name of the columns in my table and the parameters of the function are the same i didnt face any problems . If something doesnt look right please feel free to mention it.

On the other hand when i tried to create my delete function it didnt go well:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_function(firstName character varying(45)
                                   ,lastName character varying(45) ,age character varying(45))
                                
                                                                       -
RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN

DELETE FROM person
WHERE firstName = NEW.firstName AND lastName=NEW.lastName AND age=NEW.age;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

and i got this message:
**ERROR:  column reference "firstName" is ambiguous**

I know that this problem is caused because the parameters of the function and the columns have the same name . Can somebody help me out on this one?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just rename your function parameters? That's the recommended approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your feeling is correct, and that should lead to an error in recent versions of PostgreSQL.

If you cannot rename the parameters, which would be the simplest solution, qualify the parameter names in the `VALUES` clause with the function name:

```
VALUES (insert_function.firstname, ...)
```

In the case of the `WHERE` condition in the `DELETE`, qualify the table columns with the table name:

```
WHERE person.firstname = insert_function.firstname
```

Comment: I knew thta the easiest way was to just rename the parameters but i was asked to execute the function this way .